# a question about linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have a $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $E,F$ are a $k$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $E^{\perp}\cap F=\{0\}$, Does it follow that the projection of $F$ onto $E$ is all of $E$? (say we're using an orthonormal basis with repect to $E$.) If so, how to prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $v_1,...,v_k$ span $F$, and let $\Pi$ be the orthogonal projection onto $E$.
Then $\Pi v_i$ are linearly independent. If not, then for some non zero $\alpha_i$ we have $\sum_i \alpha_i \Pi v_i = \Pi \sum_i \alpha_i v_i = 0$. However, this means that $\sum_i \alpha_i v_i \in E^\bot$, a contradiction.

**Addendum**: To illustrate why the projection is taken to be orthogonal:

Take $P=\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, a non-orthogonal projection on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $E= \operatorname{sp} \{e _1 \}$, and $F=\operatorname{sp} \{e _1 +e_2\}$, both $1$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Also, $E^\bot \oplus F = \{ 0 \}$. However, $\ker P = F$, hence the projection is not all of $E$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, clearly if the projection is not required to orthogonal, this is false.

Take a basis for $E^{\perp}$, and a basis for $F$. Clearly the union of theses is linearly independent. By the fact that there are $n$ linearly independent elements in this set, we have $F\oplus E^{\perp}=\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $P$ be the orthogonal projection onto $E$.

$E=P(\mathbb{R}^n) = P(F\oplus E^{\perp})=P(F)$